# boost::program_options v1.59 breaks API compatibility

Tags: boost, boost-program-options

Since `v1.59` on `boost::program_options`, if you specify an `implicit_value` (say `3`) for a command line option, then this command line:

./myprogram --myoption 5

will no longer parse and assign `myoption` the value of `5`, instead it's assigned myoption the implicit specified value of `3`.

I would like to know if there's a way (e.g. a macro) to force the old semantic to  `boost::program_options`.

Comment: I wonder if they have ever considered that are potentially zillion programs that will have to be modified because of this change!!

Comment: Relevant links: http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_59_0.html The behaviour was a bug fix ([_"The current documentation states that if an option has implicit value, it will only consume adjacent token."_](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/commit/88dea3c6fdea8c9ea894911897b1770599c383e4)).

Comment: I would have changed the documentation